# Creating a list comprehension that repeats certain values in a list for X times and then moves on to the next item

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a very specific use-case for creating a list comprehension and I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do it. I am sure there must be a method or function that can help me, but I guess I am not aware of it.

Here is the scenario:
Following code works as expected and generates all expected variations (8 in total)

```
List_A = ["apples","oranges"]
List_B = ["meat","chicken"]
flexibility = range(2)

list = []
for a in List_A:
    results = [(day, b, a) for day in flexibility for b in List_B]
    list.append(results)
print (list)
```

result

```
[[(0, 'meat', 'apples'), (0, 'chicken', 'apples'), (1, 'meat', 'apples'), (1, 'chicken', 'apples')], 
 [(0, 'meat', 'oranges'), (0, 'chicken', 'oranges'), (1, 'meat', 'oranges'), (1, 'chicken', 'oranges')]]
```

Here is the complication. Let's assume I have a rate limit of 5 calls per second, and the list above creates 8 elements, hence I would go above the rate limit. The way I thought I could overcome this, was to create another variable to pass on to the function that will use a different accounts to make my api request. In theory, each account would make only 5 requests. Thus in my example above, the first 5 elements of the list would have account 0 and the rest 3 would use account 1.
I tried using list comprehension to achieve this, but the result is not what I expected:

```
no = [0,1,2]
List_A = ["apples","oranges"]
List_B = ["meat","chicken"]
flexibility = range(2)

list = []
for a in List_A:
    results = [(day, b, a,n) for day in flexibility for b in List_B for n in no]
    list.append(results)
print (list)
```

results

```
[[(0, 'meat', 'apples', 0), (0, 'meat', 'apples', 1), (0, 'meat', 'apples', 2), (0, 'chicken', 'apples', 0), (0, 'chicken', 'apples', 1), (0, 'chicken', 'apples', 2), (1, 'meat', 'apples', 0), (1, 'meat', 'apples', 1), (1, 'meat', 'apples', 2), (1, 'chicken', 'apples', 0), (1, 'chicken', 'apples', 1), (1, 'chicken', 'apples', 2)], 
 [(0, 'meat', 'oranges', 0), (0, 'meat', 'oranges', 1), (0, 'meat', 'oranges', 2), (0, 'chicken', 'oranges', 0), (0, 'chicken', 'oranges', 1), (0, 'chicken', 'oranges', 2), (1, 'meat', 'oranges', 0), (1, 'meat', 'oranges', 1), (1, 'meat', 'oranges', 2), (1, 'chicken', 'oranges', 0), (1, 'chicken', 'oranges', 1), (1, 'chicken', 'oranges', 2)]]
```

I get many more elements in my list than what I want. I still want the original 8 but the first five would use account 0 and the last 3 account 1.

The goal is to get this list:

```
[(0, 'apples', 'meat',0), 
 (0, 'apples', 'chicken',0), 
 (0, 'oranges', 'meat',0), 
 (0, 'oranges', 'chicken',0), 
 (1, 'apples', 'meat',0), 
 (1, 'apples', 'chicken',1), 
 (1, 'oranges', 'meat',1), 
 (1, 'oranges', 'chicken',1)]
```

How can I achieve this?
thanks

Comment: FYI, don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: The first part is just itertools.product, and the rate limit thing is a completely separate step which you handle when iterating over the previous result.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, Yes, this was just to simplify and show my example. My real code does not use the variable "list". Appreciate the feedback and support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concise way to do this combines `itertools.product` to give the combinations, with `enumerate` to give you a running counter. You can floor-divide that counter by 5 to give your "account number":

```
import itertools

List_A = ["apples", "oranges"]
List_B = ["meat", "chicken"]
flexibility = range(2)
rate_limit = 5

res = [(n, a, b, i // rate_limit)
       for i, (n, a, b) in enumerate(itertools.product(flexibility, List_A, List_B))]
print(res)
```

which gives the output list you're looking for:

```
[(0, 'apples', 'meat', 0), (0, 'apples', 'chicken', 0), (0, 'oranges', 'meat', 0), (0, 'oranges', 'chicken', 0), (1, 'apples', 'meat', 0), (1, 'apples', 'chicken', 1), (1, 'oranges', 'meat', 1), (1, 'oranges', 'chicken', 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this with a list comprehension. Use an ordinary loop, so you can increment a counter variable and the index into the `no` list. Then when the counter reaches 5 you can reset it and increment the account number index.

To get all the combinations of `List_A`, `List_B`, and `flexibility`, use `itertools.product()`.

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

accounts = [0, 1, 2]
account_index = 0
List_A = ["apples","oranges"]
List_B = ["meat","chicken"]
flexibility = range(2)

result = []
counter = 0
limit = 5

for day, b, a in itertools.product(flexibility, List_B, List_A):
    if counter >= limit:
        account_index += 1
        counter = 0
    result.append((day, b, a, accounts[account_index]))
    counter += 1

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'meat', 'apples', 0),
 (0, 'meat', 'oranges', 0),
 (0, 'chicken', 'apples', 0),
 (0, 'chicken', 'oranges', 0),
 (1, 'meat', 'apples', 0),
 (1, 'meat', 'oranges', 1),
 (1, 'chicken', 'apples', 1),
 (1, 'chicken', 'oranges', 1)]
```